# ActiveRecord using Safari Sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am build a webapp for iphone using Phonegap, and I want to create a DB on the device and not on my server.
I've seen that there is a Safari Sqlite database, but I haven't been able to find any information about using this database with active record.

Does someone knows how to do so?

Best,
Gregory

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it because your code is executed on the server and not in the browser so you won't be able to use ActiveRecord with the browser`s database.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has nothing to do with client-side database. If you want to build an application using client-side database, you need to build your application in JavaScript.

I think you should take a look an JavaScript frameworks, like [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/).